# flutterfire cannot fetch data from firebase firestore unless the path is hardcoded

Tags: flutter

[original code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQOPe.png)

If i change the .doc argument to the roomID variable, firebase wouldn't send any data back. Im confident the value inside the variable is completely same as the string. I know maybe there's some weird asynchronous stuff happening where the variable isn't set before this code runs? but the print function works fine.

Thoughts guys? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When your `roomID` changes do you see the first print statement in the logs with the right `roomID` ?

Comment: thx for your reply. There is a leading whitespace in that variable.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a leading whitespace in that variable. I thought that it's maybe the issue. I printed the length of it in the console and counted it myself, char by char. I got the same result and just ignored it. I spent a day to fix this error until my friend spotted it out for me. What a waste day....